# Is PFUser.currentUser() an array?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently trying to create an object with a pointer to the current user, however, I get an error claiming that PFUser.currentUser() is an array:

```
[Error]: invalid type for key requested, expected *_User, but got array (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.4)
```

My code is here:

```
var requests = PFObject(className: "Requests")
        requests.addObject((PFUser.currentUser()!), forKey: "requested")
        requests.save()
```

Comment: Well, what is `PFUser.currentUser().dynamicType`?

Comment: No it is `PFObject : NSObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change the formatting a bit, but here it is.

```
var sendRequest = PFObject(className: "Requests")
 sendRequest["requester"] = PFUser.currentUser()
 sendRequest.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
     (success: Bool , error: NSError?) -> Void in
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're logged in, else the PFUser is null..

The `currentUser()` function returns a `PFUser object`.
[See more here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/currentUser)

What about using this code:

```
var request = PFObject(className: "Requests")
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
   request["requested"] = user
   request.save()
}
```